# What is optimal response size for chunked transfer in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, http, transfer-encoding

I am creating a reverse proxy and I am trying to find the optimal buffer for a response size for a chunked transfer-encoding.  Currently I have it set at 4 kb.  Is this number OK, or is there a better size that I should be using.  I would like this backed up with some tests if at all possible.

I would also accept a property setting somebody knows about in the .NET framework that has a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal size is going to be rather application and network specific. There was a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282504/choosing-buffer-size-for-ftp-and-http-transfers) that offered suggestions on measuring the best chunk size given the environment.

J2ME used to default to 2KB chunks (that's client-to-server). But I have no idea what .NET defaults to. Unfortunately the [HTTP Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6.1) on chunking offers no guidance either.

Answer (score 1):

I had large file transfers that were killing the web server so I implemented chunking per this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812406

Customers immediately complained that file downloads took 3 times as long, the buffer was set to 10K.  In some cases these files are 80-100MB in size.  I upped the buffer to 200K and will post my results.

Comment: Setting it to 200K did increase the speed of the transfer to what it was previously without chunking